# Suggestions for Displaying Several RichText Paragraphs iOS5

Tags: ios5, uiwebview, uitextview

I am building an iPad app that needs to display certain RichText parapraphs

```
Title1 (bold and big font)
Description1 (rich text may contain images)

Title2 (bold and big font)
Description2 (rich text may contain images)

Title3 (bold and big font)
Description3 (rich text may contain images)

and so on.....
```

What is the best way to display this information in a ViewController?

I have looked at UIWebView and from the looks of it, it needs either a URL or a HTML String that it can load. Whereas, in my scenario, I have multiple HTML strings that need to go in different places on the screen.

Any ideas what is the best way to deal with this? Can I instead use a UITextView?

Thanks in advance.